# App Crashes on android.support.v7.widget.Space

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

My app crashes with the following error:

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Space
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.Space"

Comment: Looks like they [pulled it from v7](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Space.html), for some reason. Try v4 instead - `android.support.v4.widget.Space`.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM.

Comment: added formatting to the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with that class using the v4 reference `android.support.v4.widget.Space`